# How to set foreign key nullable?

Tags: java, jpa, foreign-keys

I have table which is defined like this:

```
@Entity
public class Shipment implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="SENDER_ID",referencedColumnName="CUSTOMER_ID", nullable=true)
    private Customer sender;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
  //  @Column(nullable=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="TARRIF_ID",referencedColumnName="TARRIF_ID",nullable=true)
    private Tarrif tarrif;




    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
  //  @Column(nullable=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="RECIPIENT_ID",referencedColumnName="CUSTOMER_ID",nullable=true)
    private Customer recipient;


    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
   // @Column(nullable=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="COURIER_ID",referencedColumnName="COURIER_ID",nullable=true)
    private Courier courier;
....
}
```

I want to delete customer/courier/tariff object, which is linked to the shipment. So basically, I want to be able to set Foreign Key to NULL.

Though nullable is set to true, glassfish says it can't be done, that foreign key constraints are being violated. Any ideas ?

Im using javaee 6, javax.persistence.api 1.0.2, glassfish 3+, and java derby db.

Comment: If a constraint is violated, it doesn't come from JPA and Glassfish, but from your database. Evenif the association is optional and the join column is marked nullable, if you have a not null constraint in the database, the database will apply it, and you'll get an exception. Change your database schema.

Comment: I would be really happy if youd tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set any reference to your object to null in "Java"/JPA before calling remove on it.  This will cause the foreign key value to be set to null.

You can configure a foreign key constraint to do this in your own DDL, but your object model (and possibly cache) would still be corrupt (better to fix your code).